# How to traverse lists containing a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, data-analysis

I am trying to traverse JSON data brought into a Dataframe.

Here is the code used to bring the data in:

```
df = json_normalize(data['PatentBulkData'])
```

Each series of the Dataframe is a list. Each list contains a list of dictionaries as represented below.

For example, here is the list of dictionaries returned when I enter `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData'][i]`:

```
[{'eventCode': 'PG-ISSUE',
  'eventDate': '2020-04-23',
  'eventDescriptionText': 'PG-Pub Issue Notification'},
 {'eventCode': 'RQPR',
  'eventDate': '2020-01-02',
  'eventDescriptionText': 'Request for Foreign Priority (Priority Papers May Be Included)'},
 {'eventCode': 'M844',
  'eventDate': '2020-01-03',
  'eventDescriptionText': 'Information Disclosure Statement (IDS) Filed'},
 {'eventCode': 'M844',
  'eventDate': '2020-01-02',
  'eventDescriptionText': 'Information Disclosure Statement (IDS) Filed'},
 {'eventCode': 'COMP',
  'eventDate': '2020-02-04',
  'eventDescriptionText': 'Application Is Now Complete'}]
```

Then, `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData'][i][j]` would return the dictionary:

```
{'eventCode': 'PG-ISSUE',
 'eventDate': '2020-04-23',
 'eventDescriptionText': 'PG-Pub Issue Notification'}
```

I would like to iterate through each entry in the `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']` to identify rows containing a specific string in `'eventDescriptionText'`.

In the above example `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']` is a Series, `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData'][i]` is a list, and `['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData'][i][j]` is a dictionary.

I would like to initially iterate through the list - and for each list iterate through the dictionary to see if 'eventDescriptionText' contains a specific string.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']` references a list, each element of which is a list of dictionaries, as shown in your example output for element `[31]` of the dataframe’s entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code.

```
for lst in df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']:
    for I in lst:
        if I.get("eventDescriptionText").find(your_string) != -1:
            # do something
            pass
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then your `i` is a list of dictionaries, because `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']` seems to be a list of lists (of dictionaries).

Comment: You might be right. Let's confirm this from the question author himself. Let's wait for the answer of your question in the comment.

Comment: For clarification, df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData'] is a list containing a dictionary.  In the above example, each dictionary includes 3 key-values.

Comment: I get this - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Then df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData'] is a list of list, as @jens said. Please verify this.

Comment: @tbb which tells me that `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']` is a _list_ of lists. [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is a dictionary function.

Comment: Truly - my apologizes.  To clarify - In the above example `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']` is a Series, `df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData'][i]` is a list, and `['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData'][i][j]` is a dictionary.

Comment: @tbb, then see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887429/how-to-traverse-lists-containing-a-dictionary#62887756).

Comment: @AstikGabani, I fixed your code, but please check the return value of `find()` against -1. As is, your code will fail if the text is found on position 0.

Comment: Hi @AstikGabani - your code does work.  For some reason - at the end of the code, I get an error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.  But the code does capture the requested string and does something.  I will need to look into why the TypeError is occurring.

Comment: @tbb, see my comment to AstikGabani: the code has a bug and needs to be fixed.

Comment: @AstikGabani: please refer to the documentation of [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), your code is still broken even after your change. Either use `if … >= 0` or (as per docs) the `in` operator.

Comment: @Jens You are right. I have updated the code. tbb Please look at the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then

```
df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']
```

is, in fact, a list whose elements are lists of dictionaries. See also [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887429/how-to-traverse-lists-containing-a-dictionary#comment-111208474) above. If that is the case, then the boring way is:

```
lst = df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']
for dicts in lst:
    for d in dicts:
        if d['eventDescriptionText'] == 'SOME TEXT YOU SEARCH FOR':
            code = d['eventCode']
            date = d['eventDate']
            # Do something with code and date.
```

Now, you could [flatten that list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) and use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
lst = df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']
for d in (d for dicts in lst for d in dicts):
    if d['eventDescriptionText'] == 'SOME TEXT YOU SEARCH FOR':
        code = d['eventCode']
        date = d['eventDate']
        # Do something with code and date.
```

Next, squeeze the test into the lists-flattening-generator as well to make the code a bit less readable:

```
lst = df['prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData']
for code, date in ((d['eventCode'], d['eventDate']) for dicts in lst for d in dicts if d['eventDescriptionText'] == 'SOME TEXT YOU SEARCH FOR'):
    # Do something with code and date.
```

The [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function doesn’t help much with readability here

```
for code, date in ((d['eventCode'], d['eventDate']) for d in filter(lambda d: d['eventDescriptionText'] == 'SOME TEXT YOU SEARCH FOR', (d for dicts in lst for d in dicts))):
    # Do something with code and date.
```

but other [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) or [more-itertools](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools) may be of use (e.g. the [flatten()](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.flatten) function).

Comment: Thanks, @Jens - I will give this a try as well.  Thanks again for your assistance!